TkInter Canvas flickering when drawing on it from a Thread
I'm trying to make a simultaneous drawing of plants, the plant is a class that contains the method get_circles() , and also is_growing() that returns the status of the plant. get_circles() returns a generator object that draws some circle on each iteration. However, when drawing in another thread, Canvas flickers a lot, which is, of course, quite unpleasant.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk

import time
from threading import Thread, Event

from tools import Color, Circle, Vec2
from plant_generator import Plant


class StoppableThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stop_event = Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()


class ThreadPainter(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, canvas, image, draw, plant):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image = image
        self.draw = draw
        self.plant = plant
        self.delay = 0.3

    def clear_canvas(self):
        """
        Clear image with plant and update canvas
        """
        self.image = Image.new("RGB",
                               (600, 600),
                               (255, 255, 255)) 
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        self.update_canvas()

    def update_canvas(self):
        """
        Show image on canvas
        """
        self.canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image(600 // 2, 600 // 2,
                                 anchor=tk.CENTER, image=self.canvas.image)

    def draw_circle(self, circle: Circle):
        """
        Draw circle on image

        Draw 3 circles, main, darker and lighter
        for 3D effect
        """
        width = 600
        height = 600
        x, y = circle.pos + Vec2(width // 2, height // 2)
        if x < 0 or x > width or y < 0 or y > height:
            return
        r = abs(circle.radius) + 1

        x0, y0 = x - r, y - r
        x1, y1 = x + r, y + r

        default_color = circle.color
        dark_color = circle.color + Color(20, 20, 20)
        light_color = circle.color - Color(20, 20, 20)
        self.draw.ellipse((x0, y0, x1, y1),
                                fill=light_color.rgb)
        self.draw.ellipse((x0 - 1, y0 - 1, x1 - 1, y1 - 1),
                                fill=default_color.rgb)
        self.draw.ellipse((x0 + 1, y0 + 1, x1 + 1, y1 + 1),
                                fill=dark_color.rgb)

    def run(self):
        self.clear_canvas()
        while self.plant.is_growing() and not self.stopped():
            for circle in self.plant.get_circles():
                self.draw_circle(circle)
            time.sleep(self.delay) 
            self.update_canvas()


class DrawPlantFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.canvas_width = 600
        self.canvas_height = 600

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, 
                                width=self.canvas_width,
                                height=self.canvas_height,
                                bg="white")
        self.start_button = tk.Button(self,
                                      text="Start", height=2,
                                      command=self.start_drawing)

        self.background = (250, 250, 250)
        self.plant_image = Image.new("RGBA",
                                     (self.canvas_width, self.canvas_height),
                                     self.background)
        self.plant_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.plant_image)
        self.current_drawing = None

        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.start_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
    
    def start_drawing(self):
        if self.current_drawing:
            self.current_drawing.stop()

        self.current_drawing = ThreadPainter(self.canvas,
                                            self.plant_image,
                                            self.plant_draw,
                                            Plant.random())
        self.current_drawing.start()


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setup_window()
        self.setup_widgets()

    def setup_window(self):
        """
        Set title ans size of window
        """
        self.title("Threading Drawing")

        self.geometry("1280x800")

    def setup_widgets(self):
        """
        Setup frames with plants 
        """
        self.plant1 = DrawPlantFrame(self) 
        self.plant2 = DrawPlantFrame(self)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.plant1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.plant2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()


Before that, I used after() to draw plants, but as soon as it became necessary to draw two at the same time, the program hung until one of the plants was drawn to the end. I did it as follows:
    def start_drawing(self):
        """
        Start drawing and generation of plant

        1. Stop all previous drawing (if exist)
        2. Get new plant
        3. Start drawing and generating new plant
        """
        try:
            if self.current_drawing:
                self.after_cancel(self.current_drawing)
            self.clear_canvas()
            self.progress_var.set(0)
            plant = self.controller.user_frame.get_plant()
            self.current_drawing = self.after(1, self.draw, plant)
        except:
            ...

    def draw(self, plant: Plant):
        """
        Draw plant while it is growing
        """
        for circle in plant.get_circles():
            self.draw_circle(circle)
        self.update_progress(plant.drawed / plant.total * 100)
        self.update_canvas()

        if plant.is_growing():
            self.current_drawing = self.after(1, self.draw, plant)
        else:
            self.update_progress(100.0)
            self.current_drawing = None

So after googling and refactoring the program using threading module, this of course solved the hang problem, but added annoying flickering
I also tried using Label instead of Canvas but that didn't do anything, nor did reconfiguring the image to Canvas (stackoverflow.com)

you should only draw from the main thread, and you need to update the image instead of creating a new one on each iteration How to update an image on a Canvas?
to call a function on the main thread simply use canvas.after method only on the drawing method, therefore the following code
self.update_canvas()

becomes
self.canvas.after(0, self.update_canvas)  # call on main thread now

and the next code
def update_canvas(self):
        """
        Show image on canvas
        """
        self.canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image(600 // 2, 600 // 2,
                                 anchor=tk.CENTER, image=self.canvas.image)

becomes
def update_canvas(self):
        """
        Show image on canvas
        """
        self.canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        if self.image_on_canvas is None:
            self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas.create_image(600 // 2, 600 // 2,
                                    anchor=tk.CENTER, image=self.canvas.image)
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image = self.canvas.image)

note you need self.image_on_canvas = None in the __init__

as I already said, after() does not help in solving the problem, because as soon as I start drawing on another Canvas, drawing on the first hangs, and after a while it shows the finished result

@killerwhale keep the multithreaded code as is, each canvas should be handled by one thread, what i am saying is that the specific call of self.update_canvas() should be called with .after(), so that the drawing will happen on the main thread, the rest of the logic should happen on other threads.
